# Populate spreadsheet with data from a list based on selections made in userform listboxes

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have created a simple user form with two list boxes in Excel and need to achieve the following:

Based on the two selections made by the user from the two list boxes, I need 'Sheet1' to be populated by data from 'Sheet2'. The data needs to be filtered so for example if I select AW17 as the Season and Footwear as the Department, Sheet1 should only be populated with clothing related to that season and footwear.

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Sheet 2 is a list of clothing styles including a lot of other information all divided into columns.

[UFLB1LB2CB1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJZMG.jpg)

[Sheet2 Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01fLc.jpg)

Image of the userform and listboxes.

Also,

I have the following code for the command button OK after the user selects the Season and Department:

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()

If Range("A3:B3").Text <> "" Then

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

'Transfer information
Cells(3, 1).Value = SeasonListBox.Value
Cells(3, 2).Value = DptListBox.Value

Unload Me

Else

MsgBox "Please select Season and/or Dept.", vbInformation, "Try Again"

End If
End Sub
```

What I want to achieve is:
It the cells where the selected Season and Dept. should appear are empty then either disable the OK button or display msgbox "Select Season and/or Dept." and do nothing.

If cells are populated then

```
'Make Sheet1 active
    Sheet1.Activate

    'Transfer information
    Cells(3, 1).Value = SeasonListBox.Value
    Cells(3, 2).Value = DptListBox.Value

    Unload Me
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the data organized on the second sheet?  You have three items here - (season) (department) (items()) - a picture of how you have this structured would be helpful.  I'm not sure if you have merged cells or even where on the second sheet data is located.  Why only one data sheet - unless you are required to only use one it would be better to have multiple sheets for each department.

Comment: I've added a snippet from Sheet 2 of the headers, due to confidential information I can't share the data below the headers.

Comment: Multiple sheets are an option as I am not required to run everything of one, we have line lists for every department and season.